# Run time analysis of inner loop

Tags: asymptotics, loops

What is the run time of the following piece of code in Big-Oh notation? The first loop runs n times in the worst case. But I am having difficulty in finding run time of nested loop which runs V / deno[i] times to be exact. So I think the total runtime would be O(n* V/deno[i])? Please correct me if I am wrong.

int deno[] = {1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 500, 1000};

int n = sizeof(deno)/sizeof(deno[0]);

// Driver program 
void findMin(int V) 
{ 
    // Initialize result 
    vector ans;

```
// Traverse through all denomination 
for (int i=n-1; i>=0; i--) 
{ 
    // Find denominations 
    while (V >= deno[i]) 
    { 
       V -= deno[i]; 
       ans.push_back(deno[i]); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Without knowing what values `deno[i]` might take and what `ans.push_back()` does, this is pretty much unanswerable.

Comment: deno[i] can take value from 1000, 500, 100, 50, 20 10, 5, 2 , 1

Comment: The array deno is given as input. push_back() appends the the argument given to it at the end of the vector 'ans'

Comment: Your code runs in $O(1)$. This is always the case when there is no input.